# How to use configured JSON options when using a custom InputFormatter?

Tags: asp.net-core

I would like to replace the default SystemTextJsonInputFormatter with a custom input formatter, either as a sub-class of TextInputFormatter, or (preferably) SystemTextJsonInputFormatter; preferably the latter, to be as close as possible to the built-in ASp.NET Core behaviour without having to duplicate code into my class, which would need to be periodically updated as new ASP.NET Core releases make changes to SystemTextJsonInputFormatter.

There is some relevant info here:

[Custom formatters in ASP.NET Core Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/custom-formatters)

Which provide this example of how to register a custom input formatter:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
   
builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.InputFormatters.Insert(0, new VcardInputFormatter());
});
```

However, I currently also have this customisation of the JSON options, like so:

```cs
internal static IServiceCollection ConfigureJsonSerialization(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(opts => {
        // Note. some of these settings are defaults, but we ensure they are set as required.
        opts.JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
        opts.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = false;
        opts.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;

        // Add our custom converters.
        opts.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new DateOnlyJsonConverter());
    });

    return services;
}
```

`opts` there is a `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.JsonOptions` object.

When using the built-in `SystemTextJsonInputFormatter`, these options make it into that formatter instance via its constructor (the relevant code appears to be in `MvcCoreMvcOptionsSetup`).

I would like to use those same JSON options in my custom input formatter, but cannot see how to obtain a `JsonOptions` at construction time (the `options.InputFormatters.Insert(0, new VcardInputFormatter());` line from above.

I will continue to look through ASP.NET Core internals to try and figure out a way, but thought I would ask here in case anyone can offer some guidance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat hacky approach is to simply copy the JsonSerializerOptions properties from the existing `SystemTextJsonInputFormatter` instance provided by ASP.NET Core, like so:

```cs
public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    internal static IServiceCollection ConfigureJsonSerialization(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers(
            opts => {
                // Search for an existing instance of SystemTextJsonInputFormatter in the InputFormatters list;
                // this is the instance provided as standard by ASP.NET Core.
                int idx = FindSystemTextJsonInputFormatter(
                    opts.InputFormatters,
                    out SystemTextJsonInputFormatter? sysTextJsonInputFormatter);

                // We expect to find the SystemTextJsonInputFormatter.
                if (sysTextJsonInputFormatter is null)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("No SystemTextJsonInputFormatter is defined.");

                // We will now create our own input formatter, and swap it in to substitute the
                // SystemTextJsonInputFormatter instance. First we have some objects to setup.

                // Copy the json serializer settings from the existing SystemTextJsonInputFormatter.
                var jsonOptions = new JsonOptions();
                CopyJsonSerializerOptions(
                    jsonOptions.JsonSerializerOptions,
                    sysTextJsonInputFormatter.SerializerOptions);

                // TODO/FIXME: Research how best to get a logger for our input formatter!
                var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder => {
                    builder.AddConsole();
                });
                var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<SystemTextJsonInputFormatter>();

                // Perform the substitution.
                opts.InputFormatters[idx] = new JsonMergePatchInputFormatter(jsonOptions, logger);
            })
            .AddJsonOptions(opts => {
                // Note. some of these settings are defaults, but we ensure they are set as required.
                opts.JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
                opts.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = false;
                opts.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;

                // Add our custom converters.
                opts.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new DateOnlyJsonConverter());
            });

        return services;
    }

    private static int FindSystemTextJsonInputFormatter(
        FormatterCollection<IInputFormatter> inputFormatters,
        out SystemTextJsonInputFormatter? sysTextJsonInputFormatter)
    {
        // Search for an instance of SystemTextJsonInputFormatter, and store it's index in the InputFormatters list.
        // Note. We expect only one instance at most, but if there is more then one then we simply take the first instance.
        for (int i = 0; i < inputFormatters.Count; i++)
        {
            if (inputFormatters[i] is SystemTextJsonInputFormatter formatter)
            {
                sysTextJsonInputFormatter = formatter;
                return i;
            }
        }

        // Not found.
        sysTextJsonInputFormatter = null;
        return -1;
    }

    private static void CopyJsonSerializerOptions(JsonSerializerOptions targetOptions, JsonSerializerOptions sourceOptions)
    {
        // Notes. A hacky but necessary approach, because we are given a pre-built JsonSerializerOptions object
        // that can't be replaced, therefore we must copy the various setting into it.
        targetOptions.AllowTrailingCommas = sourceOptions.AllowTrailingCommas;
        targetOptions.DefaultBufferSize = sourceOptions.DefaultBufferSize;
        targetOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = sourceOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition;
        targetOptions.DictionaryKeyPolicy = sourceOptions.DictionaryKeyPolicy;
        targetOptions.Encoder = sourceOptions.Encoder;
        targetOptions.IgnoreNullValues = sourceOptions.IgnoreNullValues;
        targetOptions.IgnoreReadOnlyFields = sourceOptions.IgnoreReadOnlyFields;
        targetOptions.IncludeFields = sourceOptions.IncludeFields;
        targetOptions.MaxDepth = sourceOptions.MaxDepth;
        targetOptions.NumberHandling = sourceOptions.NumberHandling;
        targetOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = sourceOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive;
        targetOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = sourceOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy;
        targetOptions.ReadCommentHandling = sourceOptions.ReadCommentHandling;
        targetOptions.ReferenceHandler = sourceOptions.ReferenceHandler;
        targetOptions.UnknownTypeHandling = sourceOptions.UnknownTypeHandling;
        targetOptions.WriteIndented = sourceOptions.WriteIndented;
        targetOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = sourceOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition;
        targetOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = sourceOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition;

        // Re-use the same converter instances; this is OK because their current parent
        // SystemTextJsonInputFormatter is about to be discarded.
        targetOptions.Converters.Clear();
        foreach (var jsonConverter in sourceOptions.Converters)
        {
            targetOptions.Converters.Add(jsonConverter);
        }
    }
}
```

I spent some time wading through ASP.NET Core source code and call stacks in an attempt to find a better/cleaner/official way, but ultimately had to give up and go with the above. Please do let me know if there are better solutions.